# Best way to disable SSH for all users?

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, vnc, ufw

For security reasons I want to turn off SSH when I don't use it and turn it on again via a VNC connection as I can connect to my web server remotely over the Digitalocean control panel's console instead, and turn on SSH that way.

Is below the best way of doing it?

```
sudo stop ssh
sudo ufw deny 22
```

And turn on SSH via VNC

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
sudo start ssh
```

Or should I use any of the below variants?

```
sudo service ssh stop
sudo systemctl stop ssh
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh stop
```

I'm on a UBUNTU 16.04 LTS server. And I want to disable SSH for all users, not only for root.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your rationale here - AFAIK VNC is *much* less secure than SSH (unless the VNC is tunneled... over SSH)

Comment: @muru It was only here I got a relevant answer though... by Serge

Answer (score 15):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS uses systemd, which means you want `systemctl`.

To prevent the service from starting automatically at boot time, use

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh.service
```

To stop currently running one, use

```
sudo systemctl stop ssh.service
```

and

```
sudo systemctl start ssh.service
```

Note that this stops `ssh` server. You can still use `ssh` client to connect to remote hosts, but with `ssh` server disabled remote connections destined to your machine will be disabled

---

If you want to completely disable the service/unit, use

```
sudo systemctl mask ssh.service
```

The above makes systemd unit files a symlink to `/dev/null`, so any start attempts will fail